# How to execute a background job with Android-Job

Tags: android, jobs

I've found out [this](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) library which seems to be very powerful, but I can't figure out how to use it.
I need to do a job which starts when Internet is connected, **even though my application isn't in foreground**. My job sends a request to a web server to get some data, and I want my job to store this data locally in a XML file.
I've checked [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/easy-job-scheduling-with-android-job-4a2c020b9742) tutorial about Android-Job library, but it schedules the job in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method, so my app would need to be in foreground.

So, is it possible to execute a job in background when Internet connection is available on Android N, or is it mandatory to have my app in foreground due to new background services restrictions?

**EDIT**

This is my logcat:

```
05-25 16:14:06.300 892-904/system_process I/ActivityManager: Force stopping clyky.cartracker appid=10117 user=-1: set debug app
05-25 16:14:06.392 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/ActivityThread: Application clyky.cartracker is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-25 16:14:06.542 13046-13052/clyky.cartracker I/art: Debugger is active
05-25 16:14:06.592 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: Debugger has connected
05-25 16:14:06.592 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:06.792 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:06.993 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:07.193 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:07.393 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:07.593 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:07.793 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:07.994 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
05-25 16:14:08.194 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker I/System.out: debugger has settled (1483)
05-25 16:14:08.289 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.731 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.777 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.821 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.870 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.911 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.954 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:08.999 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:09.041 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:09.087 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:09.136 13046-13046/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:16.632 13260-13260/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.031 13260-13260/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.103 13260-13260/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.148 13260-13260/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.221 13260-13260/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.282 13260-13260/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.338 13325-13331/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
05-25 16:14:17.461 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.830 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.904 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:17.954 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.027 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.082 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.125 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.173 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.235 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.310 13325-13325/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
05-25 16:14:18.408 13325-13325/clyky.cartracker W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=krait --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/clyky.cartracker-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@clyky.cartracker-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of that library you mentioned but you can register a broadcast receiver in your manifest that will get triggered for "CONNECTIVITY_ACTION broadcasts" here based on the connectivity state you start intent service that will perform you background job.

Note this solution will work fine prior to Nougat, but after that you will need to use Job Scheduler. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#bg-opt) the API "provides a robust mechanism to schedule network operations when specified conditions, such as connection to an unmetered network, are met. You can even use JobScheduler to react to changes to content providers".

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own Job with Service, which you want to call, for example MyJob with MyService:

```
public class MyJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "my_job_tag";

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
        getContext().startService(i);
        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static void scheduleJob() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(MyJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(60_000L) // 1 minute
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.ANY)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }
}
```

Also you need `MyJobCreator`:

```
public class MyJobCreator implements JobCreator {

    @Override
    public Job create(String tag) {
        if (MyJob.TAG.equals(tag)) {
            return new MyJob();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and init your job in `Application.onCreate()`:

```
JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new MyJobCreator());
MyJob.scheduleJob();
```

Comment: I've tried your solution with a new service, but my job is never scheduled (the `onRunJob` it's never reached)

Comment: I've tried to remove `.setPeriodic(60_000L)` because it caused my app to crash, but now it crashes when it reaches the `build` method

Comment: @Clyky You should not comment this service and it should look like here: https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-can-i-remove-the-gcm-dependency-from-my-app  , if you don't use GCM API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with `evernote/android-job` you can do a job when internet is available et and if it is not the job will be repeated after here is the documentation :

> /**
>        * Set some description of the kind of network type your job needs to have.
>        * Not calling this function means the network is not necessary, as the default is
>        * {@link NetworkType#ANY}.
>        *
>        * 
>        * 
>        *
>        * Note that if the deadline is met and the requirements aren't enforced, then your job
>        * will run and ignore this requirement.
>        *
>        * @param networkType The required network type.
>        * @see #setRequirementsEnforced(boolean)
>        * @see #setExecutionWindow(long, long)
>        */
>       public Builder setRequiredNetworkType(@Nullable NetworkType networkType) {
>           mNetworkType = networkType;
>           return this;
>       }

And to use it just do this :

```
  int jobId =  new JobRequest.Builder(YOUR_JOB_NAME.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setExtras(extras)
            .build()
            .schedule();
```

I used the jobId to stop that job in the futur.
If you need my full example there is my github where i used it : 
https://github.com/jdagnogo/Alerte-leboncoin-appart/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jdagnogo/alertlebonsoinappart/services/jobs/GetLastAppartJob.java